# How can I merge two objects with nested arrays in javascript?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have two arrays in JSON something like:

```
proj1                   proj1
  taska                   taska
    charge1                 charge1
    charge2               taskb
  taskb                     charge1
    charge1                 charge2
proj2                   proj2
  taska                    taska
  taskb                      charge1
   charge1                 taskb
                             charge1
                           taskc
                        proj3
                           taska
```

and I'd like them to merge into something like:

```
proj1
  taska
    charge1
    charge2
  taskb
    charge1
    charge2
proj2
   taska
     charge1
   taskb
     charge1
   taskc
proj3
   taska
```

I tried using jQuery's `extend` method to recursively merge, but this fails because I need the arrays to merge, and `extend` replaces arrays instead. Will I need to iterate through each level of each list, or is there a more elegant solution like `extend` that merges objects *and* arrays?

**Edit** here's a JSON example of one of my lists:

```
{
    "projects": [
        {
            "projectName": "JobIdTooManyChar",
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "name": "Process Graphics",
                    "charges": [
                        {
                            "date": "2012-06-18",
                            "hours": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-06-28",
                            "hours": "5"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Custom Software",
                    "charges": [
                        {
                            "date": "2012-06-18",
                            "hours": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-06-19",
                            "hours": 24
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Consulting",
                    "charges": [
                        {
                            "date": "2012-06-18",
                            "hours": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-06-21",
                            "hours": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "projectName": "JobIdTooManyChar",
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "name": "CAD Drawings",
                    "charges": [
                        {
                            "date": "2012-06-18",
                            "hours": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-06-19",
                            "hours": 6
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "2012-06-21",
                            "hours": 9
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/ and recurse if needed.

Comment: What kind of array is this? Can you post its structure in JSON?

Comment: @SalmanA updated with a verbose JSON example.

Comment: @jcolebrand No actually, he explained why `expand` wouldn't work and speculated about doing recursion and merging, this method merely makes it easy to merge arrays.

Comment: @TheZ I hadn't seen `merge`, but it doesn't work for the same reason as `extend` doesn't work - this isn't merely a simple object or array, it's an object with array values, which in turn contain objects with array values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery and underscore.js both see the array as a property *value* so they replace the *value* with one from the other.

I honestly believe you just need to write (expand on what they've already done) the method to expand the objects the way you need them done. For instance, with an array, does key position 1 have special meaning, or is it merely a stack/queue?

Do you need help writing just such a merge utility?